# How do i make a 4x4 grid of imageviews?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/music" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/music" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/music" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/music" />

</TableLayout>
```

This is the original XML, i just need to add more. i have an imageView that's big , so it needs to be shrunk down and copied 16 times into a 4x4 grid. I can only get it to go 4 images in one column

Comment: this is the code that gives me a 1x4

Comment: and gridview doesnt work, it keeps telling me to install some stuff so i do then it doesnt work

Comment: Define your single ImageView in XML and use it with GridView which has  columnCount 4. Or use GridLayout which has columnCount 4 and use addView() method to add ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem with the large image, but I will tell you my suggestion:

there are multiple possible solutions:

1. Since you have 16 imageViews that you wish to create, you can use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) together with a [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) . If it's important for you to see it in the xml, use [isInEditMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode%28%29) for a custo GridView, and set the adapter there to be your adapter with fake items. You should be aware of problems with the sizes of the columns/rows on the gridView , especially when changing orientations.
2. Another alternative could be the GridLayout
3. If you insist on using the TableLayout, you can have 4 TableRow instances, each has a weight of 1 . in each of them , add 4 imageViews and there each has a weight of 1.

Comment: GridView is not designed for that.

Comment: not designed for what exactly ? he wants to show 4x4 views . it can be done. of course, there are other solutions as i've written.

Comment: It can be, but GridView is for long lists with unknown lenght for example. He will get a lot of issues with it like: not changing sizes after orientation changes, not proper padding between views and blue highlighting on top and bottom if you try to sccroll it.

Comment: points taken. edited my answer. i should have known about it as i had my own experience with it and hated using it for the same scenario.

Comment: I was also doing the same thing few weeks ago and found out that Android doesn't have an appropriate view :( But in my case a could have 1 to 6 items in 2*3 grid. So the only thing that was acceptable for me is to fill layout from code.

Comment: @Lingviston true, but maybe it's not hard to implement. gridLayout is one solution, but i don't think it's good enough for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add 4 `TableRow`'s and put your `ImageView`'s into them.

Or you can create this grid from code. Like this:

```
LinearLayout container = null;
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        container = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        mGrid.addView(container);
    }
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) mLayoutInflater
        .inflate(R.layout.view_item, container, false);
        //populate the view in loop
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        container.addView(view);
    }
```

Comment: Edited. And fill free to experiment with code/layout. This is just an example.

Comment: Like me and android developer noticed you can use TableLayout with 4 TableRows and 4 ImageViews in each. If you don't want to create layout from code.

Comment: i did that but it wont let me resize the image

Comment: Try to use layout_weight and scaleType properties.